# Android Changing homepage of default browser programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, android-browser

I am trying to use the following code to set my page as the browser homepage, but it is not working:

```
Context browserContext = createPackageContext("com.android.browser", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);

SharedPreferences sp = browserContext.getSharedPreferences("com.android.browser_preferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);                 
SharedPreferences.Editor edidor = sp.edit();
edidor.putString("homepage", "http://www.mypage.com");
edidor.commit();
```

I am getting this warning:
`///data/data/com.android.browser/shared_prefs/com.android.browser_preferences.xml without permission`.

As both application process ids are different, I cannot access the SharedPreferences of Browser application.

So:

1. How do I achieve this task?
2. Are there other approaches to try, such as a javascript or web page loading?
3. Can I open `setHomepage` dialog of default browser programmatically?

Comment: have you done this ? I am in need of exactly the same

Answer (score -3):

Try after adding android.permission.ACCESS_BROWSER  this permission in your android manifest file

Comment: not working because the the shared preference is MODE_PRIVATE